# Async problem in angular, how can I get the final result after all subscribes finish?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I was trying to call an API five time with five different params, then pushes five data into one list. But due to the Async problem, the list is empty when I console.log it and says "value below was evaluated just now."

I tried to use Promise. All but I got a list of "Subscriber" or "Observable". Is there a way that I can call that API five times then get the final result after all subscribe finished?

```
applyTrialBalance() {
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
  this.xxxService.getTBreport(this.user, this.qb_company_id, JSON.stringify(this.qb_data.qb_token_json), this.tb_years[i][0], this.tb_years[i][1])
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
        this.tb_report.push([this.tb_years[i][0], data])  
        this.tb_report.sort().reverse();
    })
}

console.log(this.tb_report)// here returns empty list but "value below was evaluated just now."
}
```

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H9oD.png

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the calls and make use of the [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) rxjs operator

This is a rough outline of how to do it, you will have to tweak it to your situation.

```js
const calls = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
  let call = this.xxxService.getTBreport(this.user, this.qb_company_id, JSON.stringify(this.qb_data.qb_token_json), this.tb_years[i][0], this.tb_years[i][1]);
  calls.push(call);
}

forkJoin(calls).subscribe(([valueOne, valueTwo, up to valueFive]) => {
  // Do something with the data
})

// You can also get the data like this
forkJoin(calls).subscribe(values => {
  // Do something with the data
  // e.g. values[0]
})
```